# How can a static void class function be initialized in the header of a C++ program?

Tags: c++

I am supposed to initialize a static string, which is a private member of the class, with a setter which is a public member of the same class, from outside of the class, and in the same namespace.

Here is the code template I was given. Changing the `College` class is not allowed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class College
{
private:
    static string principal_name; // principal_name is common for all the students

public:
    static void setPrincipalName(string name)
    {
        principal_name = name;
    }

    static string getPrincipalName()
    {
        return principal_name;
    }
};

//Initialize the static principal_name variable with value "John" here

string College::setPrincipalName("John");
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Just `College::setPrincipalName("John");`? (without the `string`).  Weird kind of class, with everything declared `static` like that. And as @Remy says, you need to define the variable also somewhere.

Comment: Kind of unrelated, but why is `College::principal_name` `static` at all?  Does every college have the same principal?

Comment: @PaulSanders it is not enough to simply call `setPrincipalName()`, the actual `principal_name` variable still needs to be defined somewhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I already added that.

Comment: Having a getter and a setter function that never fails / throws an error is pointless. Just make the variable public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string College::setPrincipalName("John");` is not legal or correct.  You need to define the actual `College::principal_name` variable instead, eg:

```
string College::principal_name = "John";
```

Even then, *don't* define it in the header file itself.  Every file that includes the header will try to re-define the variable, leading to linker errors.  Define the variable one time in a separate `.cpp` file instead, eg:

College.h

```
#ifndef CollegeH
#define CollegeH

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class College
{
private:
    static string principal_name; // principal_name is common for all the students

public:
    static void setPrincipalName(string name)
    {
        principal_name = name;
    }

    static string getPrincipalName()
    {
        return principal_name;
    }
};

#endif
```

College.cpp

```
#include "College.h"

string College::principal_name = "John";
```

After that, you can use `College::setPrincipalName()` and `College::getPrincipalName()` anywhere else, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

with `c++17`, simply use `static inline`

```cpp
class College
{
    static inline std::string principal_name = "John";
};
```

Comment: fwiw, I'd suggest not using (useless) getter/setter pair.